# Determinant error bound is better than norm bound for matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

In by textbook on numerical algebra, it states that for a numerical matrix product the error bound:

$|A B - \hat{A} \hat{B}| \le c|A| |B|$

is a stronger expression than

$\|A B - \hat{A} \hat{B}\|_{\infty} \le c\|A\|_{\infty} \|B\|_{\infty}$

It also states that the latter could easily be derived from the former.  I don't really see how that is true.
($\hat{A}\hat{B}$ is the approximation to the product)

Comment: what is the norm in the first inequality?

Comment: That would be the determinant.